# PHP comment form not parsing all fields

Tags: php, html, forms, comments

I know this is basic, but I am using a php comment form on my website but it is not sending me all the info inputted into the fields, please can someone help me please.

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<form method="post" action="assets/php/mail.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Postcode</label>
    <input name="postcode" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Child's Date of Birth</label>
    <input name="dob" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Year your child will begin primary school in Reception class</label>
    <input name="year" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>I would select York Community Free School as first choice for my child</label>
    <input name="send" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
    <div class="form-button">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the PHP I'm using:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$send = $_POST['send'];
$from = 'From: York Free School Comment form'; 
$to = 'yorkfreeschool@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
```

?>

All that is been emailed to me is the name, email and message, what am I doing wrong? Please please can the community help.

Comment: There is nothing requiring the field to be filled in - they may not appear if they aren't. Also I suggest you look at HTML5 [input types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html). You should have code to validate your input data to your script in any event. Your HTML may also be badly formed - you appear to have a stray `div class="form-button">` without a closing `</div>`, and a closing div without an opening one in the form

Comment: Obviously you will get only name, email and message because that is what you put in the `$body`. Put the rest of the variable in the `$body` you will get them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the email fields into the $body variable for it be sent I only added DOB and postcode in this example

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$send = $_POST['send'];
$from = 'From: York Free School Comment form'; 
$to = 'yorkfreeschool@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];

//Look here
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message Postcode: \n $postcode DOB: \n $dob \n";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
   echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using any of the additional fields you're grabbing. If you want to have them included, you need to append them to the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- ur html code is not valid, look at submit input -->
<form method="post" action="assets/php/mail.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Postcode</label>
    <input name="postcode" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Child's Date of Birth</label>
    <input name="dob" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Year your child will begin primary school in Reception class</label>
    <input name="year" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>I would select York Community Free School as first choice for my child</label>
    <input name="send" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
    <!--</div> i think that closing div tag should go after input with id == "submit" -->
    <div class="form-button">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div> <!-- here -->
</form>
```